# Batch file set to pick a random file from preset categories is not picking a random file (keeps picking the last file!)

Tags: batch-file, random

Good evening. I enjoy modding a game in my free time, it's one those games where individual mods are packed into zip files and loaded in by simply placing said zips into a certain folder. I have hundreds of these zips and was hoping to make a batch that would pick out a random mod for me each time I use it instead of having to pick through them all myself, while placing all the unused ones into a disabled folder that I made to keep everything not being used all in one place. Every mod was prefixed with a name referring to what category it'd belong to, for example 'weapon_shotgun_GiantAngryGun9000.zip' or 'character_huck_Clown.zip'

How this batch script would work is that first it'd take every file with the specified prefixes currently in the mod folder and put them all into the disabled folder. It would then go through every single file in the disabled folder that has all the specified prefixes, pick a random file from each category, and move them into the mod folder. Currently I've gotten my batch to do all that is explained, except rather than pick a random of each, it keeps picking the alphabetically last one from each prefix list. I believe it's because the Num var being used to designate the index for the entries in the File array is not being modified or read, and in-spite my best efforts I cannot get it to work the way I'm hoping.

Any advice or solutions is appreciated, thank you for reading.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET modFolder="C:\Game\Mods\"
SET disabledFolder="C:\Game\Mods\Disabled\"
SET itemListIndex=0

::Prefix names
SET Prefix1=Weapon_Shotgun_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix1%
set /A itemListIndex+=1

SET Prefix2=Character_ThisPerson_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix2%
set /A itemListIndex+=1

SET Prefix3=Weapon_Rifle_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix3%
set /A itemListIndex+=1


for /l %%G in (0 1 %itemListIndex%) do (
    if not "!itemList[%%G]!" == "" (
        set num=0
        for %%f in (!itemList[%%G]!*.zip) do (
           set /A num+=1
           set file[%num%]=%%f
        )
        set /A pick = !random! * %num% / 32768 + 1
        echo Moving "!file[%pick%]!" to the mod folder
        move "%disabledFolder%!file[%pick%]!" %modFolder%
    )
)
```

`set file[%num%]=%%f` is echoed as `set file[]='[name of file]'` instead of the expected `set file['(index number)']='[name of file]'`

the written echo says `Moving !file[]! to the mod folder` instead of the expected `Moving (name of file) to the mod folder`

The pick variable echos as blank, implying num or random are not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET modFolder="C:\Game\Mods\"
SET disabledFolder="C:\Game\Mods\Disabled\"
SET itemListIndex=0

::Prefix names
SET Prefix1=Weapon_Shotgun_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix1%
set /A itemListIndex+=1

SET Prefix2=Character_ThisPerson_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix2%
set /A itemListIndex+=1

SET Prefix3=Weapon_Rifle_
set itemList[%itemListIndex%]=%Prefix3%
set /A itemListIndex+=1

for /l %%G in (0 1 %itemListIndex%) do (
    if not "!itemList[%%G]!" == "" (
        set num=0
        for %%f in (!itemList[%%G]!*.zip) do (
           set /A num+=1
           set file[!num!]=%%f
        )
        set /A pick = !random! * !num! / 32768 + 1
        CALL SET "PICKFILE=%%file[!pick!]%%"
        REM echo Moving "!file[%pick%]!" to the mod folder
        REM ECHO move "%disabledFolder%!file[%pick%]!" %modFolder%
        echo Moving "!pickfile!" to the mod folder
        ECHO move "%disabledFolder%!pickfile!" %modFolder%
    )
)


GOTO :EOF
```

Your issue is that `%num%` and `%pick%` are the values of `num` and ``pick` when the outer loop (%%G) was parsed, that is, *nothing*.

The classic method is to use `!num!` for the run-time value, but you are using indirection, so you'd be tempted to use `!file[!pick!]!` which is ambiguous and resolved to `pick`. The `call` uses a subshell to resolve the ambiguity.

`Move` command disarmed by being `echo`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having already received and accepted an answer, I have decided to post this to show you how I would do it.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "modFolder=C:\Game\Mods"
Set "disabledFolder=C:\Game\Mods\Disabled"

Rem Undefine existing variables
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set item 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%A="

Rem Define filename prefixes
Set "itemListIndex=0"
For %%A In (
    Weapon_Shotgun
    Character_ThisPerson
    Weapon_Rifle
) Do (Set /A itemListIndex+=1
    Set "itemList[!itemListIndex!]=%%A_")

Rem Randomize itemListIndex
Set /A itemListIndex=(%RANDOM% %% itemListIndex)+1

Rem Define files based upon itemList[%itemListIndex%] 
Set "itemFileIndex=0"
For %%A In ("!itemList[%itemListIndex%]!*.zip") Do (Set /A itemFileIndex+=1
    Set "itemFile[!itemFileIndex!]=%%A")

Rem Randomize itemFileIndex
Set /A itemFileIndex=(%RANDOM% %% itemFileIndex)+1

Rem Move itemFile[%itemFileIndex%] to modFolder.
Echo Moving "!itemFile[%itemFileIndex%]!" to the mod folder
Move /Y "%disabledFolder%\!itemFile[%itemFileIndex%]!" "%modFolder%"
Pause
```

*This way, you can easily append to the parenthesized list of prefixes, (which both significantly reduces your code and makes it simpler to maintain). It also makes more sense to randomize `itemListIndex` first, to reduce the number of returned `.zip` files for selection/moving.*